# Alternative languages to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Having recently stumbled across improvements to CSS such as [Less](http://lesscss.org) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com), I wondered if there were any similar types of languages which compile into JavaScript. I found [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), and, of course, GWT, but are there any others?

I'm not really too fond of CoffeeScript, in my opinion it doesn't really add much to my toolkit. Are there other alternative browser scripting languages which compile into JavaScript?

Comment: "I'm not really too fond of CoffeeScript, in my opinion it doesn't really add much to my toolkit" What are you looking for in a language ? Do you like GWT then?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895322/are-there-other-languages-than-objective-j-that-get-compiled-to-javascript-in

Comment: Script# is a language that gets resembles C#. The output of the tools is to translate your code into Javascript. (Think C# without most of the .NET runtime, but replaced with an API that resembles Javascript runtime. Also some support for declaring external references).  http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [traceur](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/)
- [dart](http://www.dartlang.org/)
- [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)

[List](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) of Languages that compile to JS

Answer (score 2):

You can compile C/C++ code into Javascript using [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki). So you can compile scripting language interpreter written in C/C++ into JS (for example Ruby/Python/Lua etc.)

Comment: Nice! That sounds pretty rad. Writing JS in Ruby or Python would be nice.